# Python: Eval giving NameError in function

Tags: python, eval, nameerror

I want to use `eval` to do operations to see if `a` and `b` equals `c` with some operator.

My code:

```
def Expression(a, b, c):
    operators = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
    return len([i for i in operators if eval("a () b".replace("()", i)) == c]) >= 1

Expression(1, 2, 3)
```

For some reason, this results in a NameError. Error log:

```
return len([i for i in operators if eval("a () b".replace("()", i)) == c]) >= 1
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Since the function has `a` as a parameter I don't believe `a` should be undefined. What is the problem here?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. `eval` is usually associated with risky operations, what you are missing though is likely using string interpolation you want the value of `a` not just `a` variable. Try '{} () {}'.format(a, b).replace....`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in that case `eval` try to find `a` and `b` in global scope, not function scop(it means that `a` and `b` is just valid in the function block). so you can pass the function current scope using `locals()` to `eval` like this:

```
def Expression(a, b, c):
    operators = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
    scope = locals()
    return len([i for i in operators if eval("a () b".replace("()", i), scope) == c]) >= 1
```

Then your code will work.

for better understanding try to define `a` and `b` in the global scope, then you can see it works, like this:

```
a=1
b=2
def Expression(c):
    operators = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
    return len([i for i in operators if eval("a () b".replace("()", i)) == c]) >= 1
Expression(3)
```

Also, you can pass a custom scope to eval by creating a dictionary and pass it to `eval`:

```
scope = {'a':a, 'b':b}
```

So, it was your code problem. but for the better attitude you can use what @Rakesh said before, Using formatted strings, it gets the current `a` and `b` and pass it to eval as what they have inside, like this:

```
eval(f"{a}{i}{b}") # <Python3.6 
eval("{}{}{}".format(a,i,b))
```

Also you can use [any()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/any) instead of `len() >= 1`